# Can i create multiple URL in web crawler on scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have tried to create multiple url in start_url, but in many refrences it doens't exist how to create multiple URL in crapy,

multiple URL is like tokopedia.com, olx.co.id, etc

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO! Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a good question. Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And what you have tried so far (in the form of code would be best).

Comment: start_url is a list. By placing all the URLs you want in that list you would have multiple URLs in your web crawler. `start_url = [google.com, amazon.com, yahoo.com]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, SimplifiedMain

class WebsiteSpider(Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['example1.com','example2.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example1.com','https://www.example2.com']

    # refresh_urls = True  # For debug. If efresh_urls = True, start_urls will be crawled again.

    def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
        doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
        lstA = doc.listA(
            url=url["url"])  # Get link data for subsequent crawling
        data = [{"title": doc.title.text}]  # Get target data

        return {"Urls": lstA, "Data": data}  # Return data to framework


SimplifiedMain.startThread(WebsiteSpider())
```

Comment: @NurfachriDaffa It needs to be installed first. pip install simplified_scrapy